# Problem with generate *DBML file from *SDF with SqlMetal util

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, sqlmetal

I try generate dbml from sdf file.

So I localize sqlMetal util in:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`

Sdf DB file path: `D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf`

So I try this command on generate dbml file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>sqlmetal.exe D:\DB_TEST\
Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf /dbml:D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml
```

I get this error:

```
Error : SQM1007: There is an IO error and the output file 'D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_
CE_DB.sdf\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml' cannot be opened.
```

So I try this command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>sqlmetal.exe D:\DB_TEST\
Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf /dbml:Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml
```

But I get this error:

```
Error : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\
Bin\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml' is denied.
```

On the end I try this version of command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>sqlMetal /dbml:Spiri_SQL
_CE_DB.dbml D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf
```

But I get same error:

```
Error : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\
Bin\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml' is denied.
```

I know that file Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml doesn’t exist yet, but I try generate with sqlMetal turil this file, what is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy both the SDF and DBML to a location where you have sufficient write/modify rights.

Else start the command prompt with elevated permissions (aka runas administrator).

BTW your first attempt is completely bogus.

OR do:

```
sqlMetal /dbml:D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.dbml D:\DB_TEST\Spiri_SQL_CE_DB.sdf
```